# How to find the json dynamic array using JSON path finder in node js

Tags: node.js, json, npm, jsonpath

I want to fetch some dynamic id in the below given json file using JSON path finder in npm package.

**Sample.json**

```
[
    {
        "4787843417861749370": [
            {
                "type": "Fast delivery",
                "subtype": "verizon",
                "status": "Dispatched",
                "reason": "null",
                "currency_code": "USD"
            }
        ],
        "1502698381711920904": [
            {
                "type": "Normal delivery",
                "subtype": "Cisco fiber",
                "status": "Added Cart",
                "reason": "null",
                "currency_code": "USD"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Output (The below are dynamic id from the above sample. json file):**

```
[4787843417861749370,1502698381711920904]
```

I have the similar type of the json file which contains n number of dynamic id as JSON sub array. Can someone help me to fetch all these dynamic array from the json file as like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [jsonpath-plus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath-plus) library and use `~` (for grabbing property names of matching items (as array))

Try the browser demo : https://jsonpath-plus.github.io/JSONPath/demo/

```
$.*.*~
```

[image: expression]